# Excluir um elemento de um div especifica

Tags: jquery, html

Tem o seguinte código em html:

```
<div id="lista">
   <p>Antonio Carlos Almeida Filhos</p>         
</div>
```

Como eu poderia excluir esse paragrafo somente dessa `div` sem eliminar outros parágrafos existentes na página.
Podemos utilizar `$("p").remove()`,mas nesse caso estaria retirando todos os parágrafos existentes na página.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amigo, você pode utilizar os seletores do css do mesmo jeito no javascript. Assim consegue selecionar somente o elemento escolhido.

```
$("#lista p").remove();
```

Abraços.

Comment: Eu tentei achar essa solução, mas me perdi com relação aos seletores de css

Comment: É só seguir a ordem da própria sequência do html. Primeiro seleciona a div mãe com "#lista" depois seleciona o filho que você quer excluir "p".

Comment: Ok, neste caso também so vai remover os paragrafos da div mãe "#lista", mesmo que tenha outros elementos

Comment: Exato, mesmo que tenha milhões de "p" no html, só ira remover os dentro da #lista.

Comment: ok então é isso mesmo. tks

Comment: @ÐvÐ me tira uma outra dúvida, aproveitando o caso semelhante, veja eu tenho o seguinte:
`for(i = 0; i < n_conv; i++)
{
      $("#lista").append('<p class="text-dark"> nome</p>');
}`
Eu tenho esse`for` que faz um `append` com paragrafos , tenho essa classe ` text-dark` que deveria deixar o nome em negrito, mas não é o que acontece. Se eu colocar diretamente no html funciona, mas se eu utilizar o `append` não funciona.
Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso desse jeito?

Comment: Acredito que isso é assunto para outra pergunta amigo Edson Ferrari.

Comment: ok, eu ainda preciso acostumar com o stackoverflow, tks

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa obter primeiro a `div` e depois obter os alvos filhos, algo assim:

```js
$("#lista").find("p").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lista">
   <p>Antonio Carlos Almeida Filhos</p>       
</div>

<div id="lista2">
   <p>Temer da Silva</p>         
</div>
```

Comment: Nem precisa do find. Apenas $("#lista p").remove(); já resolveria.

Comment: Eu sei @ÐvÐ, pra quem está começando é mais semântico do que prático, a pessoa não precisa dominar seletores do CSS.

Comment: Desta forma `$("#lista").find("p").remove();` se eu tiver outros seletores de css eu apenas removo os paragrafos, dentro dessa div?